# Dynamic Website Update Script

Tags: javascript, html, applet, updates

I have a website with various applets/widgets/RSS feeds. How would I go about creating a cron/script that is able to figure out when the last time one of these applets/RSS feeds was updated and store that in a database?

I'd need to be able to differentiate between an update in one feed or another. Some widgets have only pictures, one of them is the twitter widget so the content is all different.

Answer (score 0):

You could find a element which has a date for example [enter link description here](http://podcasts.engadget.com/rss.xml) has a pubDate element `<pubDate>Mon, 28 Jul 2014 14:03:00 -0400</pubDate>` or you could have a database row which told you the last article parsed from an RSS feed for each source. there would be a lot of ways this is possible, it might be worth looking on github for an opensource RSS reader and see if they have solved this problem.